# how can I set my app to run at startup,when I don't know the folder in which the app might be installed?

Tags: c#

here's my problem
I've learned how to work with registry quite recently and I'm trying to figure out something
I want my program to be set to run at startup with a click of a button
so I should write some code in the click event of my button that creates a registry file in

```
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
```

and then set the value of that registry file TO WHERE MY APP IS LOCATED
as long as I know where my app is,it is a simple job to do
BUT
my problem is that I want to make a setup file for my app,and the user will install my app wherever he/she wants
what should I do?

thanks in advance
best regards

Comment: What installation method are you using and when do you want to create the registry key? During installation or after running the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code:

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
rk.SetValue(AppName, Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

Comment: I want the registrykey to be created after the installation.and I am using VS2010 setup project.But I think I have my answer above.thanks